# how to cache extracted data in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I programmed a scraper, which extracts data from several pages. Now I realized it interrupts sometimes (for example the internet cuts of) and I lose all (already) scraped data and have to restart the scraping process.

Is there a module or solution how I can cache the data, which I already extracted, in case the script interrupts again?

Comment: write the scrapped data to a file

Comment: too broad, given nocode

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [scrapy](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) library, that have implemented several mechanisms to save data and admin your spiders.